# Wagtail document re upload with the same name doesn't purge CloudFront

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using an S3 backend for Wagtail. When I upload a pdf with the name dummy.pdf and then reupload a different file with the same name, if the document was linked in a page then the page on the frontend of the site leads to the old link. I can get around this by uploading the file with a slightly different name or publishing the page with the linked document.

Are there any solutions to this in Wagtail 2.10.1? Again I don't want to have to fork the framework.

Comment: The URL of the link to the document doesn't change on the site. This is the core issue. I need to bust the cache somehow.